# How verify server's hardware before install it into data center?

Tags: linux, validation, hardware, verification, stress-testing

could anybody help to understand me how is it possible verify and validate server's hardware configuration that I'm going to install into datacenter? The problem is that the customer bought noname server and we need validate that configuration of it correspond to spec (validate) and make sure that all components into it are working (verify).

This is first problem. The second is that servers will be hundreds...

Sorry for the question, but I'm novice into this area so I'll be thankful for any help.

A little more details: all servers are x86-base, into the future the customer will install Linux on its.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hwinfo` utility for linux system for machine hardware information.